# Capture the event click of "Open Link in New Tab" javascript or jquery - Cloaking URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that I can capture the events of click: left, right and middle button by:

```
contextmenu    
e.which
```

But, I need to capture the event click of "Open Link in New Tab":
When you do right click in a link, it shows a menu with the option "Open Link in New Tab".

How can I capture that event ?

PD: is not the right click event, is the event when you do click in "Open Link in New Tab".

The main reason is, I'm trying to cloak links for affiliated sites, but when I do right click and choose the option "Open Link in New Tab", not working, it doesn't show me the real hidden url.

I found the script searching in google but I edited the script to my needs, but I have the problem that I told above.

The code:

```
(function ($) {

    ninja_href(".ninja-href");

function ninja_href_call(e,which)
{

  var ninja_url = e.target.getAttribute('data-ninja-url');
  var ninja_target = e.target.getAttribute('data-ninja-target');

  if(ninja_target == null || typeof ninja_target == undefined || which === 3)
  {
    ninja_target = "_self";
  }

  if(which === 2)
  {
    ninja_target = "_blank";
  }


  var win = window.open(ninja_url, ninja_target);
  if (win && ninja_target == "_blank")
  {
    win.focus();
  }
}



function ninja_href(element)
{
  if(element == null || typeof element == undefined){
    element = ".ninja-href";
  }

  if (document.addEventListener) 
  {
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if(e.target && e.target.matches(element))
      {
        if (e.which === 1 || e.which === 2) 
        {
          e.preventDefault();
          ninja_href_call(e,e.which);

        }
      }
    }, false);

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
        if(e.target && e.target.matches(element))
        {
            if (e.which === 2) 
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                ninja_href_call(e,e.which);

            }
        }

    }, false);

    document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
        console.warn(e);
      if(e.target && e.target.matches(element))
      {

      }
    }, false);
  } else {
    document.attachEvent('click', function() {
      if(e.target && e.target.matches(element))
      {
        if (e.which === 1 || e.which === 2) 
        {
          e.preventDefault();
          ninja_href_call(e,e.which);

        }
      }
    });

  }

}

}(window.jQuery));
```

Any idea

Comment: You can’t, because it doesn’t happen on any element of your page that you had any control over - this is part of the browser UI.

Comment: Can you explain for what u want to detect it? Somebody can find other way maybe.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: any idea to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look below... This is how you can handle it.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function($){
    $('a').mousedown(function(event) {
        switch (event.which) {
            case 1:
                //alert('Left mouse button pressed');
                $(this).attr('target','_self');
                break;
            case 2:
                //alert('Middle mouse button pressed');
                $(this).attr('target','_blank');
                break;
            case 3:
                //alert('Right mouse button pressed');
                $(this).attr('target','_blank');
                break;
            default:
                //alert('You have a strange mouse');
                $(this).attr('target','_self"');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: excellent use, of middle click capture, how about second(left click capture)

Comment: any idea to do it ?